# How to stop ubuntu about collecting personal informations

Tags: 14.04, privacy

Ubuntu distro collects personal information while using the system here is the link http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy of how they collect personal information. Can we able to stop those process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop it<sup>1</sup> , just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget -q -O - https://fixubuntu.com/fixubuntu.sh | bash
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Fix Ubuntu](https://fixubuntu.com/)</sup>